# Пишу бота на Python на aiogram 3. Появилась ошибка. С чем она может быть связана?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram-3.x

Пытаюсь прописать в модуле user.py регистрацию с подтверждением от руководителя. Появляется ошибка

```
TypeError: Bot.send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

С чем она может быть связана?

```
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart, Text, StateFilter
from aiogram.types import (CallbackQuery, InlineKeyboardButton,
                           InlineKeyboardMarkup, Message, PhotoSize)
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import default_state
from keyboards.keyboards import game_kb, yes_no_kb
from lexicon.lexicon_ru import LEXICON_RU
from services.services import get_bot_choice, get_winner
from database.database import cur, conn
from FSM import FSMFillForm
from main import Bot as bt

router: Router = Router()
user = []
HEADID = '6159544161'


# Этот хэндлер срабатывает на команду /start
@router.message(CommandStart())
async def process_start_command(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text=LEXICON_RU['/start'], reply_markup=yes_no_kb)


# Этот хэндлер срабатывает на команду /help
@router.message(Command(commands=['help']))
async def process_help_command(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text=LEXICON_RU['/help'], reply_markup=yes_no_kb)


# Этот хэндлер срабатывает на согласие пользователя играть в игру
@router.message(Text(text=LEXICON_RU['user_button']))
async def process_yes_answer(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text=LEXICON_RU['yes'])
    base = cur.fetchall()
    base = [i[0] for i in base]
    if message.from_user.id not in base:
        await message.answer(text=LEXICON_RU['reg1'])


@router.message(Command(commands='registration'), StateFilter(default_state))
async def process_fillform_command(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(text='Пожалуйста, введите ваше ФИО:')
    # Устанавливаем состояние ожидания ввода ФИО
    await state.set_state(FSMFillForm.fill_name)


# Этот хэндлер будет срабатывать, если введено корректное имя
# и переводить в состояние ожидания ввода возраста
@router.message(StateFilter(FSMFillForm.fill_name), F.text)
async def process_name_sent(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Cохраняем введенное имя в хранилище по ключу "name"
    user.append(message.from_user.id)
    user.append(message.text)
    await message.answer(text='Спасибо!\n\nА теперь введите номер вашей группы:')
    # Устанавливаем состояние ожидания ввода номера группы
    await state.set_state(FSMFillForm.fill_group)


# Этот хэндлер будет срабатывать, если во время ввода имени
# будет введено что-то некорректное
@router.message(StateFilter(FSMFillForm.fill_name))
async def warning_not_name(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text='То, что вы отправили не похоже на ФИО\n\n'
                              'Пожалуйста, введите ваше ФИО:')


# Этот хэндлер будет срабатывать, если введена корректная группа
# и переводить в состояние проверки статуса
@router.message(StateFilter(FSMFillForm.fill_group),
            lambda x: x.text.split('/')[0].isdigit() and x.text.split('/')[1].isdigit())
async def process_age_sent(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Cохраняем группу в хранилище
    user.append(message.text)
    # Отправляем пользователю сообщение с клавиатурой
    await message.answer(text='Спасибо!\n\nТеперь мы отправим сообщение руководителю, чтобы подтвердить, что вы Адаптер!')
    print(user)
    await bt.send_message(chat_id=HEADID, text=f"Пользователь {user[1]} из группы {user[2]} запрашивает регистрацию." \
                             f"Подтвердить регистрацию: /approve_{message.from_user.id}" \
                             f"Отказать в регистрации: /approve_000")
    # Устанавливаем состояние ожидания подтверждения регистрации
    await state.set_state(FSMFillForm.wait_for_status)

# Этот хэндлер будет срабатывать, если во время ввода номера группы
# будет введено что-то некорректное
@router.message(StateFilter(FSMFillForm.fill_group))
async def warning_not_age(message: Message):
    await message.answer(
        text='Вы неправильно ввели группу!\n\n'
             'Попробуйте еще раз')


@router.message(Command(commands=['approve']), StateFilter(FSMFillForm.wait_for_status))
async def approve_registration(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Получаем ID пользователя из команды /approve_{user_id}
    user_id = int(message.text.split('_')[1])
    if user_id != message.from_user.id and user_id != '000':
        await message.answer("Ошибка: неверный ID пользователя.")
        return
    if user_id == '000':
        await message.answer("Отказ подтвержден.")
        user.append(False)
    user.append(True)
    # Отправляем сообщение пользователю о подтверждении регистрации
    await bt.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Ваша регистрация была подтверждена!", reply_markup=game_kb)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);", tuple(user))
    conn.commit()
    await state.clear()


# Этот хэндлер срабатывает на любую из кнопок меню
@router.message(Text(text=[LEXICON_RU['Abstract'],
                           LEXICON_RU['Manual'],
                           LEXICON_RU['HW']]))
async def process_game_button(message: Message):
    bot_choice = get_bot_choice()
    await message.answer(text=f'{LEXICON_RU["bot_choice"]} '
                              f'- {LEXICON_RU[bot_choice]}')
    winner = get_winner(message.text, bot_choice)
    await message.answer(text=LEXICON_RU[winner], reply_markup=yes_no_kb)
```

Помимо этого в проекте используется библиотека sqlite3 для базы данных, есть отдельные модули для клавиатуры, запуска бота, конфига, режима руководителя и текста

Уже пыталась по разному вызывать бота и прочитала всю документацию для aiogram 3

Comment: Если вам говорят, что чего то не хватает, то с чем это может быть связано? Тут вам говорят и чего именно не хватает, и где именно.

Answer (score 2):

Сама ошибка `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` появляется в тех случаях когда к методу класса обращаются извне (не из метода класса), так как в классах при выборе сестринских методов вызов идет через `self.метод()` и таким образом `Python` организует передачу `self`, нам не приходится его передавать вручную типа такого `self.метод(self)`. Но из внешней функции передать `self` просто не возможно он не известен снаружи, если об этом не побеспокоится, и не передать его туда каким-то методом.

Пример:

```
class MissingSelfError:
  def run(self):
    print('без self будет ошибка')

m = MissingSelfError
m.run()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/daniil/Desktop/err.py", line 8, in 
> m.run()
> TypeError: MissingSelfError.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Теперь что касается `aiogram` на сайте документации говориться что в 3-ей версии произошли `breaking changes` т.е. изменения влекущие невозможность полной обратной совместимости.

> **Danger**
> Breaking News:
> aiogram 3.0 has breaking changes.
> It breaks backward compatibility by introducing new breaking changes!

Поэтому раз Вы пишете `появилась`, то возможно именно с этим она и связана.

Кода в вопросе Вы разместили много, возможно больше чем нужно, а вот главного там нет. Вы импортируете бота из `main.py` однако не ясно как он там создается, на той же [странице с предупреждением](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/) есть небольшой пример с созданием бота.

Убедитесь что у Вас в файле `main` создание происходит таким же или подобным способом:

```
async def main() -> None:
    # Dispatcher is a root router
    dp = Dispatcher()
    # ... and all other routers should be attached to Dispatcher
    dp.include_router(router)

    # Initialize Bot instance with a default parse mode which will be passed to all API calls
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
    # And the run events dispatching
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Надеюсь, это поможет решить Вашу проблему.